# creating link to files on external server

Tags: permissions, files, sftp

I am compiling and running my program on an external server via ssh currently. However, it would be very easy for me if I could additionally edit the files on the server directly via my favorite IDE, instead of doing it locally and then upload via ftp.

What is the easiest way to do this?

EDIT: It is a Linux-server, Red Hat.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your server is Linux or Unix, I'd suggest setting up NFS share or Samba share on the server.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to launch nautilus, go **File**->**Connect to Server** choose **SSH**, fill in the fields. Then connect.

Or press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> in nautilus and write in the Location:

```
sftp://REMOTE_USER@SERVER_ADDRESS:PORT
```

After this nautilus mounts the ssh filesystem under `~/.gvfs`